# How can I find mentions in twitter data?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a twitter Json data base where I need to find mentions. Example :

| user | tweet |
| --- | --- |
| @ABC | @XYZ This is my first tweet ever |
| @XYZ | Hello @ABC welcome to twitter |

Here I need to display @XYZ and @ABC from the tweet column. How can I do that in pyspark?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to display the rows that contain mentions in user column or in tweet column?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to create the column "user" by parsing the column "tweet". Regular expressions are a great tool for this.

Your code should end up like this:

```
result = df.withColumn('user', regexp_extract(col('tweet'), '@([A-Z])\w+', 1))
```

(You'll need to tinker with that regexp_extract function and the regex filter.)